# Windows 10: best place to put command prompt program

Tags: command-line, installation, command-prompt, windows-10

In Windows 10 on a desktop or laptop, what is the best place to put a command prompt program that I wrote myself or acquired from the net. I have one admin account on each of my computers, a standard account for my own routine use, and additional standard accounts for each friend or visitor. I want the admin account to be able to modify the program, and the standard accounts to be able to execute it.

I'm leaning toward putting it in the public folder and setting custom permissions so standard users will only be able to execute. Is this the best choice?

I'm reasonably experienced with Windows 8.1 but just bought a new laptop with 10.

Comment: it's a program. why not in \program files? that's what that dir tree is for.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of having trouble doing what I wanted in \program files, even logged in as administrator, in Windows 8.1. Since M'soft tends to make things tougher with time, I suspected working with \program files would be worse in 10.

Comment: The `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` directories are only write accessible to the Administrators group by default. This means you will have to UAC elevate in order to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Public User folder and restrict it with sharing options or security and set accessbility to administrator, define who can execute or edit.